# dynamics crm - Call JS function from grid

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm-2013, microsoft-dynamics

I am trying to call JS function from gridview or dashboard. 
I know how to do it from a form but wonder how to do it in grid view ? 
(too add some colors)

A simple **step by step** explanation would be appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You cannot add Javascript to grids or dashboards directly. You can only add Javascript to buttons in the ribbon.

Changing the colors in the CRM UI are unsupported customizations and should be avoided as they can easily break in future product releases.

Comment: Thank you. I have dashboard that calls a JS function (I have the JS file) probably by a buttons. 
1. How can I find which button fire the functions ? 
2. Where is the JS file located in the solution ? where I can see it ? 

Thanks again

Comment: Include the entity the dashboard is part of to a fresh CRM solution. Export the solution.zip. In the zip open the customizations.xml en look for the Javascript function name. The function call is part of a RibbonDiffXml belonging to an entity. If you cannot find the function call in the customizations.xml, it can still be located in the application ribbon, which is a separate part of your CRM solution package.